# Http request - log

Tags: http, firefox, log

Estou desenvolvendo um processo Curl, e para isto estou verificando as paginas necessárias para gerenciar as urls.

Contudo há um pagina que realiza `Http Request 302` (redirecionamento), e eu não estou conseguindo capturar ela pois o processo é muito rápido.

Pesquisando um pouco encontrei este loguer [Http logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging), contudo o arquivo gerado é muito confuso e complicado de interpretar, e este [App](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/http-request-logger/), que não tem suporte.

Alguém saberia algum outro modo de gerar um log HTTP?

#### Editado Add Imagens da requisições

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Tela inicial

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Tela com autorização do certificado digital

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Enviada a requisição (aqui é onde eu não consigo pegar a resposta). Para ver esta url eu tive de apertar `ESC` forçando a parada.

Comment: Acho que não compreendi corretamente, mas talvez o [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) te ajude...

Comment: @KaduAmaral agradeço, mas eu uso linux, eles ate tem um opcão para linux aqui ericlawrence.com/dl/MonoFiddler-v4484.zip, mas pelo que vi do download teria de executar um window para então gerar os files de linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não certo de que compreendi a pergunta, mas se você já usa o Firefox, a melhor forma de obter o log de todo o tráfego desde o primeiro pedido HTTP é usando o Developer Toolbar que já vem no próprio navegador.

O shortcut para ativar a barra é `Shift + Ctrl + i`.
Em seguida clique em Rede (como mostra o círculo verde na imagem abaixo).
Recarregue a página com `F5` e veja o rastro dos pedidos HTTP. É tudo que você precisa. Firebug também tem um ótimo HTTP tracer, mas o do firefox deveria ser o suficiente pra você e para 90% dos casos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ah, e não existe essa de request de 302/301 ser tão rápida que não estará nos logs. Se o servidor retorna um 302/301 (consequentemente com um header Location) isso estará no log HTTP. Firefox faz isso muito bem!

Comment: sim eu faço uso deste, contudo como comentei o processo é de 302 que possui um `Location: ###` no Header e eu não consigo ver pra onde é este `Location:`, pois ele envia para esta pagina e ela executa mais um `Location`, no caso um duplo `Location` e ai que esta, eu não consigo pegar a do meio.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Certamente há algo errado. Pode me mostrar a URL inicial de todo o processo?

Comment: eu creio que você não ira conseguir acessar, pois são urls do governo e é necessário ter cerificado digital para acessar, mas vou aditar a pergunta edicionando algumas imagens.

Comment: Editado. Adicionei as requisições.